# How to use Python condensed For loop with if else

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a list from another list:

```
lista = [u'http://www.fetise.com/apparel/shirts',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/apparel/tees',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/apparel/tops-and-tees',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/belts',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/cufflinks',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/jewellery',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/lighters',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/others',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/sunglasses',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/ties-cufflinks',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/wallets',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/watches',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/boots',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/casual',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/flats',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/heels',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/loafers',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/sandals',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/shoes',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/slippers',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/sports',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/innerwear/boxers',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/innerwear/briefs',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/deos',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/haircare',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/perfumes',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/personal-care',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/shavers',
 u'apparel/tees/gifts-for-her',
 u'footwear/sandals/gifts-for-her',
 u'footwear/shoes/gifts-for-her',
 u'footwear/heels/gifts-for-her',
 u'footwear/flats/gifts-for-her',
 u'footwear/ballerinas/gifts-for-her',
 u'footwear/loafers/gifts-for-her']
```

By using this:

```
["http://www.fetise.com/" + i for i in lista if "http://www.fetise.com/" not in i]
```

Output is:

```
[u'http://www.fetise.com/apparel/tees/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/sandals/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/shoes/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/heels/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/flats/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/ballerinas/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/loafers/gifts-for-her']
```

But I need this output:

```
[u'http://www.fetise.com/apparel/shirts',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/apparel/tees',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/apparel/tops-and-tees',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/belts',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/cufflinks',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/jewellery',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/lighters',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/others',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/sunglasses',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/ties-cufflinks',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/wallets',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/watches',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/boots',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/casual',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/flats',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/heels',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/loafers',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/sandals',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/shoes',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/slippers',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/sports',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/innerwear/boxers',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/innerwear/briefs',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/deos',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/haircare',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/perfumes',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/personal-care',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/shavers',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/apparel/tees/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/sandals/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/shoes/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/heels/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/flats/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/ballerinas/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/loafers/gifts-for-her']
```

Can someone please tell me how I can use `if else` with `for` loop in the condensed form...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a conditional expression on the left-hand side of the list comprehension:

```
["http://www.fetise.com/" + i if "http://www.fetise.com/" not in i else i for i in lista]
```

This produces:

```
>>> pprint(["http://www.fetise.com/" + i if "http://www.fetise.com/" not in i else i for i in lista])
[u'http://www.fetise.com/apparel/shirts',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/apparel/tees',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/apparel/tops-and-tees',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/belts',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/cufflinks',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/jewellery',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/lighters',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/others',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/sunglasses',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/ties-cufflinks',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/wallets',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/watches',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/boots',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/casual',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/flats',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/heels',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/loafers',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/sandals',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/shoes',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/slippers',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/sports',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/innerwear/boxers',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/innerwear/briefs',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/deos',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/haircare',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/perfumes',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/personal-care',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/shavers',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/apparel/tees/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/sandals/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/shoes/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/heels/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/flats/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/ballerinas/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/loafers/gifts-for-her']
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not filter, you need change the value only for new list:

```
["http://www.fetise.com/" + i if  "http://www.fetise.com/" not in i else i for i in lista]
```